How can I use j/k to select next/previous completion suggestions in Intellij IDEA/CLion/RustRover(also use IdeaVim)?
In VSCode I can set keybindings.json like this:
{
"key": "j",
"command": "selectNextSuggestion",
"when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
},
{
"key": "k",
"command": "selectPrevSuggestion",
"when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
},
{
"key": "space",
"command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
"when": "suggestWidgetVisible && editorTextFocus"
},
{
"key": "Tab",
"command": "hideSuggestWidget",
"when": "suggestWidgetVisible && editorTextFocus"
},

When and only when suggestWidget is visible(in insert mode, of course), j/k should do action "selectNextSuggestion/selectPrevSuggestion" at once without any other action. (If suggestWidget isn't visible, j should delay because I set jj => Esc)
I don't know how to achieve this in Jetbrains IDE.
I ask gpt and search in google, the problem still exist.
I set ctrl+j/ctrl+k for 'Settings - Keymap - Editor Actions - Up/Down', it works. But setting j/k don't work for 'Settings - Keymap - Editor Actions - Up/Down'.
I also set ideavimrc like that:
inoremap j <c-n>
inoremap k <c-p>

It works but I can't type j/k anymore...
GPT's suggestion also doesn't work:
inoremap <expr> j (pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "j")
inoremap <expr> k (pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "k")

For more information:
https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/discussions/898

First of all: I'm not using IdeaVim myself. 1) Will setting that shortcut to Other | List Actions | Select Next Row action change anything? (normally (outside of IdeaVim) uses the same shortcut as plain Down action) 2) There is also a dedicated Other | Select Next Completion Option action -- try this one as well.

@LazyOne I tried j, Ctrl+j and Shift+j for Other | Select Next Completion Option action, Ctrl+j and Shift+j works while j has no effect.
For Other | List Actions | Select Next Row, they don't work at all.
It seems jb doesn't allow single key map?

I can assign j or k as a shortcut, no issues here. But then they do not work indeed. Here it is a dilemma: is it a person trying to type a letter or should it trigger the assigned shortcut? The key with a modifier is easier to decide in this case. I guess that's why vim/IdeaVim have those different modes (insert/select/command...).

Sorry, no better ideas -- but check for possible related tickets here -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM . P.S. This one VIM-1408 talks about Ctrl+j and Ctrl+k for navigating in the lists, and that's already works. But that's not what you are after.
